# What are tasks run by Windows Task Scheduler with "highest privileges" actually doing?

Tags: windows, permissions, scheduled-tasks

I am able to run a `takeown` from a Windows Task Scheduler task using my own credentials and it succeeds where I have access. But this is not the same as running `takeown` as an administrator-- I am simply taking ownership of a file that I have the right to by being part of a group with `SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP`.

Again, I am under the assumption that this is NOT the same as elevating a process to administrative rights. If this is not the case, then it would seem that any user specified to be used for running the task must be part of the Administrators group.

Is there a way to determine if this checkbox is simply running the process as the user but "with administrative/Administrators group" permissions or if it's something else.

Comment: Yes, it is actually.

Comment: When you say when you *run as an administrator* does that mean you type in an explicit credential such as a domain administrator or just picking the *run as administrator* option? Running as an administrator and running as administrator are not necessarily the same thing so you might clarify this other else others may think it's the "usual" run as administrator which it may be but...

Comment: Also to me I would think asking what the equivalent something is using Win32 would be a programming question more appropriate for SO community perhaps. Is this about taking ownership of a file or running a process as another or more privileged user account as your wording of this inquiry seems a little confusing. Maybe there's something I'm missing but those are my thoughts with much kindness and respect!

Comment: I've removed the Win32 portion and update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that user accounts that are part of the Admins group have 2 tokens - a low-security token and a high-security token. The low-security token is used by default, but "Run with Highest Privileges" says "Please use my high-security token, if I have one."

I don't know if any other groups of users normally have 2 (or more) security tokens.